# Python SimpleCookie Access Using CherryPy

Tags: python, cookies, cherrypy

I'm having some issues retrieving cookies sent by the client on the server using the python module cherrypy.

In the web browser I can see the cookies in Chrome's Web Console by going to Resources -> Cookies -> localhost. And then I have 3 cookies with the following values.

[image: Chrome web cookies]

And on the server side I have the following information from the Eclipse debugger:

[image: cp2]

My question is why don't foo and release_id show up in the keys? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

NOTE:

```
cookies = cherrypy.request.cookie
```

Javascript code for setting the cookies:

```
$(function() {

// Functions from W3C Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString() + ";";
    var path = "path=/;" // Accessible to all.
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires + path;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

setCookie("foo", "bar", 1 );
setCookie("release_id", "2", 1 );
});
```

Comment: Please show the code for populating foo and release_id.

Comment: @AndrewKloos I've added the Javascript code.

Comment: Oh I see... the cherrypy isn't really involved at this point.  Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: My question is why would the cookies show up in the cherrypy.request.cookie dictionary, but then cherrypy.request.cookie['foo'] fails with a KeyError?

Comment: ok, well try to redirect after the js sets the cookie and see if cherrypy has the key pair for the next request.  Also, are you sure your session is sticking around and not being recreated each request?

Comment: I made a dumb mistake in my python code, mistaking response for request. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the `cookies.keys` is not `cherrypy.response.cookie`?

`cherrypy.response.cookie` != `cherrypy.request.cookie`

From the debugger print-screen perspective, seems ok to have`cherrypy.response.cookie` with just the`session_id` key at this point.